# PHP multiple inserts with sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have the following issue:

I have a button that sends a php file, so that it inserts a series of records into a table, suppose table 'A', this file regularly inert between 100 and 1000 records each time it is called, along the php file, several validations are made for (somewhat heavy) to update a couple of fields of that record.

the point is that when 2 or more people execute this process in the same second, or one is executed while another is inserting data, there are lines that are not updated.

what is this about?
(I'm getting the ID max of the table just after inserting the data)

with SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM A

ID = int autoincrement

---

Regularly if there are 500 records the process can take up to 10 seconds to insert and update all records

Comment: Please add your code to your question with the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54131548/edit) link.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition. Please add code, and table structures. Are you using auto incrementing fields?

Comment: Why do you need `SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM A` if it is auto increment? Please add the relevant code, it sounds like you might be executing this in the wrong order. You shouldn't run a `select` to retrieve the ID of the last record. Use the current connection and retrieve its last inserted id.

Comment: the code is soo very extense

Comment: user3783243: I need update this row after executing the validation(something heavy)

Comment: Hard to say just knowing that you have something "extensive" and "very heavy" isnt a lot to go on. Add the queries you are running in the order you execute them. I'm guessing the `max` is getting the wrong id when you select it later in the process. In PDO the function is http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php to retrieve the id created by the current connection.